# \marginpar with options

Tags: marginpar

I was trying to understand what Leslie Lamport said in his book about `\marginpar` options.  He says that

> ... `\marginpar[$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$}` makes an arrow that points towards the text, whichever margin the note appears in.  (Page 59)

I am not sure what he meant by "text".  I was hoping that it is the non-marginal text and the arrow would appear in the margin before the margin text.  The following is an experiment to test this hypothesis.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is normal text.%
\marginpar{\em This is a marginal note.}

\vspace{100pt}
This is normal text.%
\marginpar[$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$}{\em This is a marginal note.}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the hypothesis is false.

[image]

Is it possible to make the arrow followed by the marginal note appear in the margin?

EDIT: Apparently, I did not make myself clear in my first attempt.  As you can see in the second example (\marginpar with options) the marginal text (in italic) which is supposed to be in the margin is not in the margin anymore.  What I was hoping to see is the following.

[image]

If this is not what the options for `\Marginpar` are there for, then I do not see why I need these options.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but doesn't the arrow point towards the text?

Comment: The fact that `\marginpar[<left>]{<right>}` takes only two arguments (`<left>` being set on the left of an even page and `<right>` being set on the right of an odd page) is visualized by the fact that your third "argument" - in your 2nd example - is set as part of the text body, and not as part of `\marginpar`. I think [this note](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex2e/latex2e_117.html) explains it really well.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I tried to make it clear with an edit.  Hope I succeed.

Comment: You are looking for `\marginpar[{\em This is a marginal note.}$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow${\em This is a marginal note.}}` or `\marginpar[\emph{This is a marginal note.}$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$\emph{This is a marginal note.}}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

lamport didn't say anything about additional text when using the arrows. what he did say is that if you use the option, that's what goes on the odd page instead of what's in the required argument. each argument must be complete with what you want in that margin.

Answer (score 19):

What that meant was that in two-sided layouts, marginal text will change sides depending on whether the page is even or odd – and the optional argument to `\marginpar` will make it set different text in each case. A more full example would be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
Odd page\marginpar[$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$}
\clearpage
Even page\marginpar[$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$}
\end{document}
```

On an odd page, it sets `$\Leftarrow$` in the margin. On an even page, it sets `$\Rightarrow$`. So the arrow is always pointing toward the *body* text.

To get an arrow pointing toward the margin note, just say:

```
\marginpar{$\Rightarrow$ Some text}
```

Or for an arrow that always points *from* the body *to* the margin:

```
\marginpar[Some text$\Leftarrow$]{$\Rightarrow$ Some text}
```

Comment: This (starting from To get an arrow pointing towards the margin note ... in your answer) is an interesting interpretation.  Perhaps, you are right.  However, this is not what Lamport said in his book.  Quoting Lamport: `... to make an arrow pointing to the text, you need a left pointing arrow in the right margin and a right pointing one in the left margin.`  Further down he explains: `the first argument is optional and the second argument is mandatory.  The command \marginpar[$rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$} makes an arrow that points towards the text, whichever margin the note appears to be in.`

Comment: @Sony That means the *body* text. See my more complete example with the `book` class.